# Unable to receive data with libusb

Tags: c, embedded

I want to send and receive data from device to pc and vice versa. I am sending the string, but not able to receive it fully. Example: Sent string is `Hello`, and the output is:

```
Received:H
Error in read! e = -4 and received = 5
```

---

```
#include <string.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

    #define BULK_EP_OUT     0x01
    #define BULK_EP_IN      0x81

    /*find these values using lsusb -v*/

    uint16_t VENDOR = 0x0483;
    uint16_t PRODUCT = 0x5740;
    int main(void)
    {
        int ret = 1;    //int type result
       struct libusb_device **usb_dev;
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        struct libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;
     struct device_handle_expected;
    //struct libusb_device_handle device_expected_handle = NULL;
        struct libusb_device *dev, *dev_expected; 
        char *my_string, *my_string1;
        int e = 0, config;
        char found = 0;
        int transferred = 0;
        int received = 0;
        int length = 0;
        int i=0;
        int count;

        /*struct libusb_device *dev;
        struct libusb_device **devs;
        struct dev_expected;*/

        // Initialize libusb
        ret = libusb_init(NULL);
        if(ret < 0)
        {
            printf("\nFailed to initialise libusb\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
            printf("\nInit successful!\n");

        // Get a list of USB devices
        count = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &usb_dev);
        if (count < 0)
        {
            printf("\nThere are no USB devices on the bus\n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("\nToally we have %d devices\n", count);

        while ((dev = usb_dev[i++]) != NULL)
        {    

            ret = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
            if (ret < 0)
                {
                printf("Failed to get device descriptor\n");
                libusb_free_device_list(dev, 1);
                break;
            }

            e = libusb_open(dev, &handle);
            if (e < 0)
            {
                printf("Error opening device\n");
                libusb_free_device_list(dev, 1);
                libusb_close(handle);
                break;
            }

            if(desc.idVendor == 0x0483 && desc.idProduct == 0x5740)
            {
               found = 1;
            break;
            }
        }//end of while
        if(found == 0)
        {
            printf("\nDevice NOT found\n");
            libusb_free_device_list(usb_dev, 1);
            libusb_close(handle);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nDevice found");
           // dev_expected = dev;
            //device_handle_expected = handle;
        }

        e = libusb_get_configuration(handle, &config);
        if(e!=0)
        {
            printf("\n***Error in libusb_get_configuration\n");
            libusb_free_device_list(usb_dev, 1);
            libusb_close(handle);
            return -1;
        }
        printf("\nConfigured value: %d", config);

        if(config != 1)
        {
            libusb_set_configuration(handle, 1);
            if(e!=0)
            {
                printf("Error in libusb_set_configuration\n");
                libusb_free_device_list(usb_dev, 1);
                libusb_close(handle);
                return -1;
            }
            else
                printf("\nDevice is in configured state!");
        }



        if(libusb_kernel_driver_active(handle, 0) == 1)
        {
            printf("\nKernel Driver Active");
            if(libusb_detach_kernel_driver(handle, 0) == 0)
                printf("\nKernel Driver Detached!");
            else
            {
                printf("\nCouldn't detach kernel driver!\n");
                libusb_free_device_list(usb_dev, 1);
                libusb_close(handle);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        e = libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
        if(e < 0)
        {
            printf("\nCannot Claim Interface");
            libusb_free_device_list(usb_dev, 1);
            libusb_close(handle);
            return -1;
        }
        else
            printf("\nClaimed Interface\n");

        int nbytes = 64;
        my_string = (char *) malloc(nbytes + 1);
        my_string1 = (char *) malloc(nbytes + 1);

        memset(my_string, '\0', 64);//The C library function void (an unsigned char) to the first n characters of the string pointed to, by the argument str.
        memset(my_string1, '\0', 64);

        strcpy(my_string, "Hello");
        length = strlen(my_string);

        printf("\nTo be sent: %s", my_string);

        e = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, BULK_EP_OUT, my_string, length, &transferred, 0);
        if(e == 0 && transferred == length)
        {
            printf("\nWrite successful!");
            printf("\nSent %d bytes with string: %s\n", transferred, my_string);
        }
        else
            printf("\nError in write! e = %d and transferred = %d\n", e, transferred);

       // sleep(3);
       i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        {
            e = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, BULK_EP_IN, my_string1,length, &received, 0);  //64: Max Packet Length
            if(e == 0 && received == length)
            {
                printf("\nReceived:");
                printf("%c", my_string1[i]); 
             sleep(5);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nError in read! e = %d and received = %d bytes\n", e, received);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);
    libusb_free_device_list(usb_dev, 1);

        libusb_close(handle);
        libusb_exit(NULL);

        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty certain the bulk in transfer will transfer the entire buffer at once(up to 64--or 512 if you're doing high speed--bytes), not a byte at a time.

You're iterating over the size of the expected buffer and doing a bulk in for each byte, and only printing out the first byte.

Get rid of the for loop on the read and change your printf() to be printf("%s\n",my_string1);

Comment: There does in fact appear to be an implementation issue here as you describe.  But it **not a safe assumption** that all data will be returned in a single read, or even that every read will yield data until the full message is obtained, unless it is known that the entity being talked to is fully synchronous with the USB implementation.  An obvious counterexample would be a USB serial converter, but even a task running on the same MCU as the USB interface may generate or commit messages to buffers asynchronously from an interrupt mechanisms which drains those buffers in response to USB polls.

Comment: The risk of passing a buffer containing a potentially truncated message to printf() as if it were a null-terminated string should be obvious - indeed, one really should not be relying on the remote end to provide the termination at all.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!!! COMPLETELY ITS WORKING THANK U SO MUCH Russ Schultz....THANK U SO MUCH FOR UR HELP :-)